# How to use custom tags while profiling CPU with DevTools

Tags: dart

I am profiling CPU with DevTools. I see there is an option to select items by custom tags. How can I setup custom tags in my app?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:developer';
...
void doSomething() {
    final originalTag = getCurrentTag();
    UserTag('doing_something' ).makeCurrent();
     
    ...

    originalTag.makeCurrent();
}
```